# Why can't I connect to a hidden SSID in Edubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, networkmanager

I'm running a godforsaken version of Edubuntu and I'm trying to get it to connect to a wifi with a hidden SSID. I've scoured the internet for the past hour or so, trying to find anything similar and the closest I could find was mention of Kubuntu and an issue with KDE, but that solution doesn't work for me.

Adding the network manually does seem to locate the network, but every time I type the password to connect to it, it literally does nothing. Is there a way to do it manually or am I locked out of the internet forever?

I'm not really proficient in all things Linux, so I'd appreciate a lengthy answer on how things are set up, as well as how to "fix" it.

Comment: Are you using network manager? Could you consider disabling the hidden ssid bu... feature?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your desktop so we can help determine if you're using NetworkManager or not.

Comment: If you solved this problem please post your solution

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to add a hidden network like so using NetworkManager.

#### Step #1 - open NetworkManager's main menu

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

#### Step #2 - Click "Connect to Hidden Network"

[image: ss #3]

#### Step #3 - Add the SSID of the "hidden network"

[image: ss #4]

Comment: I don't have that kind of thing here, otherwise I'd have found it.

Comment: @RevanIvanovski welcome to Stack Exchange! maybe you didn't mean it that way, but that comment comes off rude and curt. please remember that we're just trying to help; if we give the wrong answer, it's often because we're operating on insufficient information. try adding details to your question (like the screenshot that slm requested) and you'll probably get better results.

Comment: @slm as a side note, anyone who doesn't recognize the system monitor applet ([one of 23](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2009-April/msg00313.html)) that you're using is probably pretty confused by what is apparently fire next to your volume indicator.